# How to get the image name of an NSTextAttachment from NSAttributedString

Tags: cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I have a Mac app that reads formatted text with images stored as `NSAttributedString`. I want to convert this into HTML including images.

Getting the HTML works fine, I can even enumerate the attached images, but I cannot get to the actual file names of the attached images. I need those for the resulting HTML.

Getting the HTML:

```
let htmlData = try attrString.dataFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length), 
documentAttributes: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType])
```

produces:

```
<p class="p1"><img src="file:///Untitled%202.jpg" alt="Untitled 2.jpg"></p>
```

Enumerating over the attached images:

```
    attrString.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName,
        inRange: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length),
        options: [],
        usingBlock: {attachment, range, _ in

        if let attachment = attachment as? NSTextAttachment,
            let fileWrapper = attachment.fileWrapper,
            let data = fileWrapper.regularFileContents
        {
            // This prints <NSTextAttachment: 0x7fe68d5304c0> "Untitled 2.jpg"
            // But there's no API to get the name?
            print(attachment.description)
        }
    })
```

So I end up with `NSTextAttachment` instances, but no way to determine the actual file name  ("Untitled 2.jpg"). `NSFileWrapper.filename` returns `nil` and I don't see an API to get the name from the text attachment.

The frustrating part is that the information is in the text attachment. If I print its debug description I see the file name:

```
<NSTextAttachment: 0x7fe68d5304c0> "Untitled 2.jpg"
<NSTextAttachment: 0x7fe68d533d60> "Pasted Graphic.tiff"
```

How can I access the file name? (without parsing the debug description ;)

Comment: `fileWrapper.preferredFilename`?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference: use `fileWrapper.preferredFilename` instead of `fileWrapper.fileName` (thanks @Willeke). Who would have thought there were two properties...

Comment: This dos not work anymore

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely ridiculous that NSTextAttachment doesn't have properties for image name and image url.

I subclassed NSTextAttachment and added these properties when I initialize my custom class.

Ex:

Subclass:

```
import Foundation

class CustomTextAttachment: NSTextAttachment {

    var imageURL: String?
    var imageTitle: String?

}
```

Implementation:

```
let textAttachment = CustomTextAttachment()
textAttachment.imageTitle = title
textAttachment.imageURL = url
```

Now when I tap the image:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

    print("Tapped custom text attachment")

    if let commentTextAttachment = textAttachment as? CustomTextAttachment, let title = commentTextAttachment.imageTitle, let link = commentTextAttachment.imageURL {
         print("Got title \(title) and link \(link) for attachment")
    }

    return true
}
```